# JavaFX: Video doesn't play instantly

Tags: java, http, javafx

I am trying to play a video in my JavaFX application.

The video is stored on a GoPro Camera which my computer is connected to through Wifi.

The issue lays in the fact that it takes a long time for the video to load. For example, a six-second video will takes 1-2 minutes to load.

I am unsure of what is causing this. However, after searching I was able to find a quote from Java's documentation that may be helpful: "It is recommended that MPEG-4 media to be played over HTTP be formatted such that the headers required to decode the stream appear at the beginning of the file. Otherwise, playback might stall until the entire file is downloaded." As a beginner though, I don't really understand what this means.

I am looking for a way to display the video without having the file downloaded on the hard drive if in any way this is possible.

Here is my code which is essentially all I've tried.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Title");

    WebView view = new WebView();
    view.getEngine().load("http://10.5.5.9/videos/DCIM/100GOPRO/GH010003.MP4");
    view.setPrefSize(300, 275);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(view));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Wasn’t this question posted previously?

Comment: Yes it was posted previously. The thread was closed so I deleted it and re-posted to add clarity and detail.